# Не устанавливается дружественный заголовок в столбцах таблицы ADO.NET

Tags: c#, ado.net

Подскажите пожалуйста в чем может быть дело. Есть простой код

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\lab\HELLOTEST.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from users", connect.ConnectionString);

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    adapter.Fill(ds);

    Console.WriteLine(ds.Tables[0].Columns[0].ColumnName);
    ds.Tables[0].Columns[0].Caption = "BlaBla";
    Console.WriteLine(ds.Tables[0].Columns[0].ColumnName);
}
```

В нем я ожидаю получить имя столбца до "переименования в дружественное" = Id, а после переименования "BlaBla", однако столбец не переименовывается. Почему ?

Comment: Потому что вы меняете Caption, а выводите ColumnName. Почему вы решили, что смена Caption изменит CoumnName?

Comment: Я пробовал разные способы, работает только если использовать `ds.Tables[0].Columns[0].Caption` , но мне кажется , что это не правильно

Comment: Что именно неправильно? :) в вопросе нет описани проблемы, которую вы пытаетесь решить своим кодом. Вы хотите поменять ColumnName?

Comment: Я прочитал, что Caption позволяет определить дружественное имя для столбца и следовательно ColumnName должно изменить имя тоже (это я уже сам так решил). Однако этого не происходит. И тогда я запутался в том, зачем вообще этот  Caption нужен, если по сути он ничего не делает. К сожалению ни в книге не в инете я не нашел практических примеров его использования.

Comment: Caption будет отображаться как заголовок столбца контролах, которые умеют сами генерить свои колонки по таблице - всяких там DataGrid, GridView и прочих. Больше ни на что Caption не влияет. Вся работа с колонками в коде должна идти через ColumnName.

Comment: Теперь понятно. Спасибо. Сделайте это как ответ, пожалуйста.